# PySpark: Find if a value present in another dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, pyspark-pandas

I have a dataframes like below. Tried Join and isin functions but not getting the expected output like below. Not sure what I was missing. Appreciate if someone can help. Thanks.

DF1:

| Name | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| Tom | A |
| Mike | B |
| John | C |

DF2:

| Approved_Grades | Description |
| --- | --- |
| A | Approved grade |

Expected Output:

| Name | Grade | Approved |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | A | Yes |
| Mike | B | No |
| John | C | No |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use 'join' in pyspark to join tables and then using conditions to filter out the result. Check the solution below.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data1 = [('Tom', 'A'),
     ('Mike', 'B'),
     ('John', 'C')]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data1, ['Name', 'Grade'])

data2 = [('A', 'Approved grade')]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data2, ['Approved_Grades', 'Description'])

merged_df = df1.join(df2, df1.Grade == df2.Approved_Grades, 'left') \
.withColumn('Approved', when(col('Approved_Grades').isNull(), 'No').otherwise('Yes')) \
.drop('Approved_Grades', 'Description')

merged_df.show()
```

Please use the above code and try if that works. thanks

Comment: Thanks Sarim. This is working as expected. Thank you.